# Hide rows in spreadsheet range containing a value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet containing a list of all possible project tasks for different types of project in a range, and a column in the range which states to which project it relates.

In cell A1 I have a dropdown box of different project types - containing the values "Custom API" and "Custom File".

The data range is C3:E10, and example data is shown in the Example Data.

```
Column A: Task name
Column B: Task Duration
Column C: Task Owner
Column D: Project Type
```

What I'd like from some vba code is:

- On selecting "Custom API" from the dropdown in A1, all the tasks in the range with the Project type "All" and "Custom API" to be shown, and all "Custom File" project task rows to be hidden.
- On selecting "Custom File" from the dropdown in A1, all the tasks in the range with the Project type "All" and "Custom File" to be shown, and all "Custom API" project task rows to be hidden.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Address = "$A$1" and Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("B4:E10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Dim taskList as Range
    Set taskList = Range(Range("E4"),Range("E4").End(xlDown))

    Dim taskCheck as Range
    For each taskCheck in taskList
        taskCheck.EntireRow.Hidden = taskCheck <> Target
    Next

  End If

End Sub
```

[image: Example data]

Comment: Hi, purpose of this site is not to write the code for you but to help you resolve any issues that you may have with your code or to help make improvements to your code. Have you written any code? If so, please provide the code. Saying that, you could just use Pivot tables with a Slicer to achieve this. You don't need VBA for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really just setting up an AutoFilter without header dropdowns.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then

        Range("B4:E10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        If AutoFilterMode Then AutoFilterMode = False
        With Range(Cells(3, "E"), Cells(4, "E").End(xlDown))
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(Cells(1, "A").Value, "All"), _
                        Operator:=xlFilterValues, VisibleDropDown:=False
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

You can clear the AutoFilter and show all values by adding an asterisk (e.g. `*`) to your list of values for the A1 dropdown.

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. Make sure that the spelling of the items in A1 match with that in the test column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 03 Jan 2019

    ' set these two constants to match your sheet
    Const FirstDataRow As Long = 4
    Const TestClm As String = "E"

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Tgt As String
    Dim C As Long
    Dim R As Long

    ' (If the address is $A$1 it can't have more than one cell)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Tgt = Target.Value
        Rows.Hidden = False
        C = Columns(TestClm).Column
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(FirstDataRow, C), Cells(Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp))
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With
        With Rng
            Arr = .Value
            For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
                Rows(R + FirstDataRow - 1).Hidden = Not (CBool(StrComp(Arr(R, 1), Tgt, vbTextCompare) = 0) Or _
                                                    CBool(StrComp(Arr(R, 1), "All", vbTextCompare) = 0))
            Next R
        End With
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```